# Lambda or LINQ for result

Tags: c#, .net, linq, asp.net-core, lambda

I have got a Feedback table from the user and feedback class contains steps.

Steps can be Achieved (A), Didn't Achieve (DA) or Achieved with Prompt (AWP)

```
Name    Step1             Step2         Step3         Step4                 
-----------------------------------------------------------------------
Zoinal  A                  AWP            A             DA  
Oomesh  A                  DA             DA            DA  
Marta   A                  DA             A             AWP 
MrBean  AWP                AWP            DA            A
```

BUT also wanted to show the number of each different achievement status. In the table something like this:

```
Name    Step1               Step2         Step3           Step4  
summery:  A=3,AWP=1,DA=0  A=0,AWP=2,DA=2  A=2,AWP=0,DA=2  A=1,AWP=1,DA=2                
-----------------------------------------------------------------------
Zoinal  A                  AWP            A              DA 
Oomesh  A                  DA             DA            DA  
Marta   A                  DA             A             AWP 
MrBean  AWP                AWP            DA            A


public class FeedbackModel
{
    public int FeedBackID { get; set; }
    public List<FeedbackStepModel> FeedbackSteps { get; set; }
}

public class FeedbackStepModel
{
    [Key]
    public int FeedbackStepID { get; set; }
    public int FeedbackID { get; set; } = 0;   
    public int StepNumber { get; set; }
    public string StepDetail { get; set; }
    public string AchievementStatus { get; set; }
    public virtual FeedbackModel FeedBackModel { get; set; }
}
```

I tried to do

```
var fullList = feedbackRepository.Feedbacks;
```

and two "for each" loops

```
foreach (var item in fullList)
{
     foreach (var step in item.FeedbackSteps)
     {
         //               
     }
}
```

I am sure there is an easy way to do it with LINQ. Can anyone help, please.

Comment: Are there always 4 steps?

Comment: Also, what is the `i` in `list[0, i]`?

Comment: No there is more steps. Don’t worry about list[0,i]pls

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understood it you want group counts by Step and status if you want this as sub array you can do it like so

```
var groupCount = from feedback in feedbacks
                 from step in feedback.FeedbackSteps
                 group step by step.StepNumber into stepsByNumber
                 select new
                        {
                            StepNumber = stepsByNumber.Key,
                            CountsByStatus = from byStep in stepsByNumber
                                             group byStep by byStep.AchievementStatus into byAchievement
                                             select new { AchievementStatus = byAchievement.Key, Count = byAchievement.Count() }
                        };
```

If you just wanted double grouping then like this

```
var groupCount = from feedback in feedbacks
                 from step in feedback.FeedbackSteps
                 group step by new { step.StepNumber, step.AchievementStatus } into stepsByNumber
                 select new { stepsByNumber.Key.StepNumber, stepsByNumber.Key.AchievementStatus, Count = stepsByNumber.Count() };
```

Edit: after some more thinking for `IQueryable` you should always use query 2 and then do sub lists in memory because the first might lead to multiple query executions or just an not supported exception it depends on the query provider. With `IEnumerable` not really sure witch one is better.